# How can you do an ifdef guard for m4 macro file includes?

Tags: m4

For C header files, you can prevent multiple inclusion of a header file like:

```
#ifndef MY_FOO_H
#define MY_FOO_H

[...]

#endif
```

How can I do the same thing in m4 such that multiple `include()` macro calls to the same file will only cause the contents to be included once?

Specifically, I want to do an ifdef guard that involves using macro `changequote` ( I'll not clutter my code with `dnl`'s):

Originally, when I do the following, multiple inclusions still corrupts the quotes:

changequote_file.m4:

```
ifdef(my_foo_m4,,define(my_foo_m4,1)
changequote([,])
)
```

changequote_invocation.m4:

```
include(changequote_file.m4)
After first include invocation:
[I should not have brackets around me]
`I should have normal m4 quotes around me'
include(changequote_file.m4)
After second include invocation:
[I should not have brackets around me]
`I should have normal m4 quotes around me'
```

Invoked with `m4 changequote_invocation.m4` yields:

```
After first include invocation:
I should not have brackets around me
`I should have normal m4 quotes around me'


After second include invocation:
[I should not have brackets around me]
`I should have normal m4 quotes around me'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most straightforward way is an almost-literal translation of the `cpp` version:

```
ifdef(`my_foo_m4',,`define(`my_foo_m4',1)dnl
(rest of file here)
')dnl
```

So if `my_foo_m4` is defined, the file expands to nothing, otherwise its contents are evaluated.

Comment: I think that does work, under normal circumstances ( and answers my question, so thanks!).  The kicker is that I'm doing something a little crazy since we can't have m4 interpret <backtick> and ' as quotes since the next tool uses those characters as valid input and we don't want users to have to do yet another string escape.  I'm trying to import a file that does a `changequote` command, but only have `changequote` execute once, regardless of how many times that include is executed.  Anyways, I'll post another question and make you dredge up some really crazy old m4 hackery.

Comment: So use the above in your changequote file.

Comment: Ah, you've thrown down the gauntlet.  Let me post the code and see if you can ravage it :-)

Comment: Ah, I get it, if the quotes are changed that won't fly.  Start the lines with a sequence starting with your language/program's comment character (say, `--!` for comment sequence `--`), then do ``changecom(`--!')`` so on later inclusions `m4` will ignore the commands.

Comment: Ah, a little bit of SQL injection attack for the betterment of the world, eh?  Ok. I think I can figure that out.

Comment: In fact, better:  ``dnl @@@@ changecom(`@@@@') changequote(`%<',`%>')`` as the file, substituting your quotes and possibly changing the comment token to suit your project.  Note that `changecom` only affects `m4`'s comment character, and it's usually not so good to have it be the same as the underlying tool's comment character.  (Switched comment sequence out of paranoia over where `m4` accepts the default `#`.)

Answer (score 2):

I think there are in fact 2 question in yours :
- How to do it
- why it doesn't work in my case.

The way to do it is almost as you've done, but you need to quote everything

```
ifdef(`my_foo_m4',,`define(`my_foo_m4',1)
  changequote([,])
')
```

The problem is the second time you include the file, the quote have been changed, so you should in theory include the following file (you've change the quote to `[`,`]` so all the files you include from now should use `[`,`]` shouldn't they ?):

```
ifdef([my_foo_m4],,[define([my_foo_m4],1)
  changequote([[],])
])
```

but you include the same file with the original quote therefore
Youw ifdef is on the symbol `` `my_foo_m4' `` (which is probably invalid) not `my_foo_m4`
and the else bit

```
define(`my_foo_m4',1)
  changequote([,])
```

is not quoted (not between []) and so evaluated whatever the result of the test is, meaning it call changequote with `,` , ie it calls

```
changequote(,)
```

Which disable the quote.